# Terms to describe age groups

Tags: single-word-requests

I have three age groups that I want to distinguish in my research project.

They are as follows:

- 18-45 years - I have called this group *young adults*
- 46-65 years - I have called this group *adults*
- 66 years and over - I have called this group *seniors*

Is there a better way (one word) to describe the 18-45 age group? I don't like the term *young adults*. (*Adults* and *seniors* work fine for me!)

Comment: whippersnappers?

Comment: Any reason why you're not breaking the 18-45 group into, say, 18-30, and 31-45?  Just curious...

Comment: I agree with J. R. I would not expect to be included in a young adult group, and I'm 45.  I understand that technically it might be correct, but I don't think I have much in common with a 20 year old physically, mentally, etc.

Comment: What @Julia said. I'm not *quite* in OP's "senior" group, but I wouldn't want to be thus labelled in a couple of years time. I think OP would be better advised to simply call them **Groups A, B, and C**. Whatever - this is hopelessly subjective, and not really a matter of "commonly-recognised English language usage".

Comment: Wow!  To still be a young adult at 38 makes me feel all giggly.  I'm an adult at this point I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just ***adults***?  I would recommend a breakdown like this:

> - **18-45 years** - adults
> - **46-65 years** - middle-aged
> - **66 years and over** - seniors

Answer (score 1):

What about *prime adult* or *early adult*?  From the Wikipedia entry for '[young adult](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_adult_%28psychology%29)':

A **young/prime adult**, according to Erik Erikson's stages of human development, is generally a person between the age of 20 - 40, whereas an adolescent is a person between the age of 13 - 19,[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_adult_%28psychology%29)[2] although definitions and opinions vary. The young adult stage in human development precedes middle adulthood. **A person in the middle adulthood stage is between the ages of 40 - 65. In maturity, a person is 65 years old or older.**